# Can I send data from Android to iPhone

Tags: android, ios, iphone, bluetooth, wifi-direct

I know that this question has been asked before many times but not recently and the API have changed so Google might have fixed some bugs. I was thinking it might be possible with two ways.

**1st:** Using Bluetooth Low Energy API of Android and then use android as central mode to scan for Bluetooth devices(iPhone). That is similar to what [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18052593/3065448) edoardotognoni asked, which it is seems after some seconds iPhone is rejecting him. I am still currently reading about this post and the [raised issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=58725) he made but I mentioned it in case someone knows something has changed.

**2nd:** Using and WiFi-Direct. About this method I have not found anything but If it is possible for two Droids to connect why can't it be possible for a Droid and an iPhone to connect. I have read about that matter this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20982773/3065448).

I also found this example on GitHub [iPhone part](https://github.com/GitGarage/BLEMingleDroid), [Android part](https://github.com/GitGarage/BLEMingleDroid).
Unfortunately I am not very good with xcode so I don't know exactly what is written in the iPhone part.

**edit:** Actually after searching I already found that it is possible with BLE but not with WiFi-Direct since iPhone does not support it. Of course being able to do it does not mean it is easy. Despite that though I have not yet found concrete proof because all I have seen is theories, an xcode that I don't understand and an Android code which seems to work when I checked it, but I have not run it.

Any help will be much appreciated, sorry for the long post!

Comment: please ask a more concrete question so we are able to answer it, of course it is somehow possible to transfer data, what are your constraints? what do you want to achieve?